# How do I parse and execute all the SQL statements separately within a file?

Tags: java, mysql, regex

Let's say I have a .SQL file that could potentially contain ANY type of statement, be it CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, or even an entire database dump. The idea is to parse the contents of this file so the statements get sent to the engine separately instead of executing the whole chunk.

At first I tried using regular expressions and splitting on `;`, but the problem with this is that it breaks when it encounters a procedure or function because of the syntax. For example...

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `calcCost`(cost FLOAT, price FLOAT) RETURNS decimal(9,2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
  SET profit = price-cost;
  RETURN profit;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Splitting by `;` here would transform this into 8 different statements, whereas I need this one to remain as one. By the way, the character used for the `DELIMITER` keyword could change.

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `calcCost`(cost FLOAT, price FLOAT) RETURNS decimal(9,2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
  SET profit = price-cost;
  RETURN profit;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Would this be doable using Regular expressions and if so, how would I do it? What's the regex expression? The Java tag is because I expect answers based around Java's regex engine and utilities.

Edit: the contents of the SQL file are unknown to me until the user loads it into my program. I can't manually add anything to it before my program loads it.

Comment: *FYI:* CREATE, UPDATE, and DELETE are **not queries**. They are SQL *statements*. A SELECT statement is a *query*.

Comment: @Andreas edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this be doable using Regular expressions?

No.

> How would I do it?

As you've noticed yourself, the *delimiter* is changeable. So you need to look for the `DELIMITER` command.

Also, you can rely of SQL files like that to only put one statement per line, i.e. you only need to look for the delimiter at the end of lines.

So:

- Set initial `delimiter = ";"`, and create an empty buffer (`StringBuilder`)
- Read the file one line at a time:

  - If buffer is empty and line is `DELIMITER` command:

    - Update `delimiter`
    - `continue` loop
  - Add line to buffer, including a line terminator
    *Remember, `readLine()` removes line terminator*
  - If line ends with delimiter:

    - Remove delimiter from end of buffer
    - Execute command in buffer
    - Clear buffer
- End Loop

Comment: I think I can sort of work with this. I'm already out so can't test right now, but I will see what I can do. If you could provide some sample code I'd be grateful, if not that's fine too.

Comment: Re-reading your answer, I can't understand what you meant by `Also, you can rely of SQL files like that to only put one statement per line,`. Does this mean that your method wouldn't work for statements that take more than one line? e.g: `CREATE TABLE` and most `CREATE`s? Because the files that are fed to my program should allow a `CREATE TABLE` statement that takes several lines. (Most DB dumping applications such as `mysqldump` format the files like that) and my program needs to be compatible with them.

Comment: @Morgan No, *"only put one statement per line"* is about not putting two statements on a single line. For not having a single statement span multiple lines, I would have said *"only use one line per statement"*. --- The entire point of the *buffer* in my answer is to collect multi-line statements, i.e. to collect lines until a *delimiter* is found, which *is* the entire point of this exercise, right?

Comment: Done, I implemented your answer. I'm open to any improvements if any. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this to read SQLs from a file. 
(It might or might not be tricky with regex, but my not so deep knowledge of regex made me do it this way)

Summary:

- Create a `Map<String, String>` which store the query_name and the actual SQL query.
- Populate the map gets populated when I load that DAO so that all the queries related to that DAO are in the map.
- Individual queries are in a SQL file.

> Sample DAO code:

```
    private static final Map<String, String> SQL_MAP;

private static final String GET_PERSON_USING_ID;

static
{
    try
    {
        SQL_MAP = Util.readConfigureMap(<MyCurrentClass>.class, "<sql_file>");
    }
    catch (IOException iE)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception: ", iE);
    }

    GET_PERSON_USING_ID                                      = SQL_MAP.get("get_person_using_id");
}
```

> Sample Util code:

```
public static final String
    CONFIG_KEY_START = "---[",
    CONFIG_KEY_END = "]";

public static Map<String, String> readToMap(Class iClass, String iFileName)
    throws IOException
{
    final InputStream vResourceAsStream = iClass.getResourceAsStream(iFileName);

    try (Scanner vScanner = new Scanner(vResourceAsStream))
    {
        Map<String, String>
            vMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        String
            vCurrentKey = null;

        StringBuilder
            vValueBuffer = null;

        boolean
            vSeeFirst = false;

        while (vScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String
                vLine = vScanner.nextLine();

            if(vLine == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            vLine = vLine.trim();

            if(vLine.isEmpty())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(vLine.startsWith(CONFIG_KEY_START))
            {
                if(!vSeeFirst)
                {
                    vSeeFirst = true;
                }

                if(vCurrentKey != null)
                {
                    vMap.put(vCurrentKey, vValueBuffer == null ? null : vValueBuffer.toString());
                    vValueBuffer = null;
                }

                vCurrentKey = vLine.substring(CONFIG_KEY_START.length());
                if(vCurrentKey.endsWith(CONFIG_KEY_END))
                {
                    vCurrentKey = vCurrentKey.substring(0, vCurrentKey.length() - CONFIG_KEY_END.length());
                }

                continue;
            }

            if(!vSeeFirst)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(vValueBuffer == null)
            {
                vValueBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else
            {
                vValueBuffer.append('\n');
            }
            vValueBuffer.append(vLine);
        }

        if(vCurrentKey != null)
        {
            vMap.put(vCurrentKey, vValueBuffer == null ? null : vValueBuffer.toString());
        }

        return vMap;
    }
}
```

> Sample sql file

```
---[get_person_using_id]
select a.name from person a where id = ?
```

Comment: The SQL in the file is dynamic. I have to load and read it as is, I can't manually add anything to it beforehand.

Comment: Dynamic? do you mean that contents of the SQL file change during program execution or SQL file contains multiple queries of a different type? cause your question does not specify about former.

Comment: The SQL file contains multiple queries of each type potentially. It could contain anything. The user drags and drops it to my program, so I don't know what it could have inside.

Comment: ok, but is there a way for you to append a delimiter when query ends (which definitely can't be ; )

Comment: I could probably manipulate the string contents of the loaded file.

Comment: Then this will work, one problem which I am thinking could be is defining key for the map(which in this case is the query name)

Comment: It could work but I'd need to identify when a statement starts and ends, and that's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working (as far as I've tested) implementation of Andreas' answer. It does exactly what I wanted. This should be compatible with the type and format of scripts most Database dumpers generate.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/myscript.sql")))) {
    String line;
    String delimiter = ";";
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (buffer.length() == 0 && line.startsWith("DELIMITER")) {
            delimiter = line.split(" ")[1];
            continue;
        }
        if (line.startsWith("--") || line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        buffer.append(line.replaceFirst("\\h+$", "")).append("\n");
        if (line.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            String statement = buffer.toString().replace(delimiter, "");
            System.out.println("{\n" + statement + "}"); //print the statement to console for debugging purposes
            //TODO execute the statement
            buffer.setLength(0);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //TODO handle IOException
}
```

Comment: Code will fail if line with delimiter has whitespace after the delimiter. Might be good to just trim all lines of *trailing* whitespaces, e.g. ` buffer.append(line.replaceFirst("\\h+$", "")).append("\n")`

Comment: I see what you mean =).
But wouldn't `buffer.append(line.trim()).append("\n");` be more readable?

Comment: That would also remove *leading* spaces, ruining the formatting of the SQL. *Functionally* it's fine, but looking at the SQL afterwards, e.g. if it is logged, would be affected.

Comment: Gotcha. I edited the answer now. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Don't replace the delimiter with a `;`. As a standalone statement, it doesn't need a delimiter (nothing to delimit / separate). Just remove the delimiter.

Comment: Like this then? `buffer.toString().replace(delimiter, "")`